# Getting the ip address of an ftp server in python

Tags: python, ssh, ftp, ip-address

I've connected to a database using `ftplib` as shown below.

```
import ftplib
sitename = 'ftp.ensembl.org'
connection = ftplib.FTP(sitename)
connection.login()
```

But because I want to use `ssh` with an argument of user@host, I believe I need the ip address of the server instead of the url of the ftp site. Is there any code to find and store the ip address of an ftp server within `ftplib`?

Comment: Why exactly can't you or do you not want to use `ssh user@ftp.ensembl.org`?

Answer (score 1):

for ssh, you need to use paramiko : http://www.paramiko.org/

here :
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.open_sftp

best regard

Answer (score 0):

The hostname `ftp.ensembl.org` is just a name for the IP address.

In absolute majority on TCP applications/libraries you can use hostname and IP address interchangeably (HTTP/web browser being notable difference).

So with any Python SSH library, you will be able to use the host name too, just as you can use it with ftplib.

---

That being said, to find an IP address, you can for example use the `ping` command:

```
C:\>ping ftp.ensembl.org

Pinging ftp-ensembl-ext.sanger.ac.uk [193.62.203.85] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 193.62.203.85: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=48
Reply from 193.62.203.85: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=48
```

So the IP address of your FTP server is `193.62.203.85`.

Or google for ["DNS lookup"](https://www.google.com/search?q=DNS+lookup).

---

To address your actual problem: To use the SSH from Python, you do not need an IP address, but rather an SSH library.

Only of the most commonly used SSH libraries for Python is [Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can translate a host name to IP address easily in Python using the `socket` library:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('www.microsoft.com')
'184.85.88.154'
>>> socket.gethostbyname('ftp.ensembl.org')
'193.62.203.85'
```

However, I suspect you don't need to do so, as `ssh` and other utilities will accept hostnames or IP addresses interchangeably.  If they require an IP address only, it is usually documented as such.